# Exporting https certificate fails with 'dotnet dev-certs' tool

Tags: dotnet-dev-certs

I am trying to use the 'dotnet dev-certs' tool to export an https certificate to include with a Docker image. Right now I am using:

```
dotnet dev-certs https -v -ep $(HOME)\.aspnet\https -p <password>
```

and I get the error:

```
Exporting the certificate including the private key.
Writing exported certificate to path 'xxx\.aspnet\https'.
Failed writing the certificate to the target path
Exception message: Access to the path 'xxx\.aspnet\https' is denied.
An error ocurred exporting the certificate.
Exception message: Access to the path 'xxx\.aspnet\https' is denied.
There was an error exporting HTTPS developer certificate to a file.
```

The problem I see is that no matter what path I supply to export the certificate to I get the same 'Access to the path  is denied' error. What am I missing? I know this command has been suggested in numerous places. But I cannot seem to get it to work.

Thank you.

Comment: It would be good to know what environment you are running this in. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

The export path should specify a file, not a directory. This fixed the issue for me on Mac:

`dotnet dev-certs https -v -ep ${HOME}/.aspnet/https/aspnetapp.pfx -p <password>`

Comment: That did not fix it for me

Comment: macOS Catalina, .net core 3.1

Comment: Tested and working on Windows 10 with powershell as administrator.
`dotnet dev-certs https -ep ${home}\.aspnet\https\aspnet.pfx -p <password>`

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu users:

1. install libnss3-tools:

   `sudo apt-get update -y`

   `sudo apt-get install -y libnss3-tools`
2. create or verify if the folder below exists on machine:

   `$HOME/.pki/nssdb`
3. export the certificate:

   `dotnet dev-certs https -v -ep ${HOME}/.aspnet/https/aspnetapp.pfx`
4. Run the following commands:

   `certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t "P,," -n localhost -i /home/<REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_USER>/.aspnet/https/aspnetapp.pfx`

   `certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t "C,," -n localhost -i /home/<REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_USER>/.aspnet/https/aspnetapp.pfx`
5. exit and restart the browser

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#ssl-linux

Comment: Thanks this works. I failed on linux mint to get chrome to trust the dotnet localhost cert for hours by following what is written in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#ssl-linux

The differences I see between yours and theirs is that you're using local user directories and exporting / trusting the cert as a pfx file. I'm not sure why yours works when theirs doesn't .. but I'm happy it works.

Comment: Hi, i get "Unix LocalMachine X509Store is limited to the Root and CertificateAuthority stores." on step 3.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was I was using .Net 5 under CentOS 7.8. Uninstalling .Net 5 and using .Net Core 3.1 SDK instead solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that in windows, if I run this command in bash:

`dotnet dev-certs https -ep $env:USERPROFILE\.aspnet\https\Aspnetcoreapp.pfx -p thepassword -t`

Resulted in the error:

`... There was an error exporting HTTPS developer certificate to a file.`

But if I run it under powershell, it completes fine.

**I would say the reason for the diffference is due to the way bash and powershell read system paths like $env:USERPROFILE etc**

Hopefully this small detail helps someone!